# Protect PHP registration form from overflow?

Tags: php, forms

I need some tips on protecting PHP user registration form i creating from overflow e.g. hacker submits specific strings that are too long and overflows etc.

On HTML form i created length 20-30, 50 max for input textarea, but can disable this using e.g. firebug debugger for firefox just edit code and remove maxchars part from tag.

I think i need to make php check whatever string is 30 chars length for certain field and only then process registration if all fields match orig size, but is that all i can do or there are some other steps i can take to make sure?

Also i got upload image field and upload small video, is this too much security flaw and should be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Verification MUST be done server side, even if is nice to have it on client side.
So when you get the values from the form in your PHP script, the first thing to do is to validate the POST or GET values. I would recommend [Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html), but if is too complicated you can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions from PHP. For string length you can use the [strlen](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function or implement a filter_var with a callback to a lenght checking function that you define.

Answer (score 1):

Such an attack against HTML forms is unknown to me.
You can check data length, along with other verifications, but it's not that big deal.

There is no security flaw in uploading videos itself. But of course there can be flaws in particular realization. But it hardly belongs to that notorious "buffer overflow" problem.